# PostgreSQL OS suggestion

Tags: postgresql, operating-system, performance

Hi guys we are on the way to start developing a big web platform. For db server we choosen postgresql. Would you suggest an OS for the postgresql server (we are looking for the maximum performance)?
Thanks

P.S. sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest **a platform that you feel comfortable with**. As [Jeff suggested](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001198.html), it is usually easier to throw faster hardware at a problem than human time.

This reasoning is based on theses main ideas :

1. Usually the database is only ***marginally*** faster given **different OS**.
2. The **high order optimisations** are usually in **tuning the database** or the **requests**. Not really in switching OS.
3. If you have **more knowledge** on a OS, you can take usually **more juice out from it**. Whereas if you take an OS that you are **not really familiar with**, but that is *supposed* to be faster, it might **kick your back in unexpected ways**.

That said, as answered before **an *NIX-based OS would be better right now**, since PostgreSQL has still deep roots in a *NIX world. **But this is becoming less and less an issue with the 8.x line**.

Comment: Yeah, if you truly need a fast DB, why not use a cluster or something like that?

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for the opinions!
Actually we are still at the planing stage of the platform so now is the time to consider all the major aspects of it. (at a later stage this might be too late)

@djangofan: utilizing postgresql cluster is the obligatory minimum but imho we should first think about the OS. In this way of words i would like to ask you for opinion about Slony-I and pgpool? Pros & Cons?

Thanks again

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you stay on a Unix based platform. There is still a large difference in performance on Windows in large scale delployments. (Said as one of the guys who made the port..)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *nix based, Linux would be great if it is possible because you can get the package easier with the built-in package manager (e.g apt for debian, yum for fedora, etc). Because Postgres is originally made for *nix based OS. The port to windows is only recently and as you can see on several threads here on Stackoverflow, Postgres does not perform as good on Windows as it is on *nix based OS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The server maintenance is not so high prio. We need to gain maximum performance from the system.

What you think if we go with FreeBSD or Solaris?

Comment: FreeBSD is really good for server as it is robust and secure enough. Solaris is also good especially on SPARC. If you also want support then you should go with Solaris, but then you must build by yourself from the source.